# Add 2 query where other query is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add to query but the other query sometimes the value is NULL

```
SELECT (a.column1+b.column2)/2 from (SELECT COUNT(column1) from table 1) a,
                                    (SELECT COUNT(column2) from table 2) b
```

The results of these query is like

```
(26248+NULL)/2 which gives NULL as a result
```

What result I want supposed to be 13124.

Is there anyway I can make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

You can use coalesce

```
 SELECT  (coalesce(a.column1,0)+ coalesce(b.column2,0))/2
```

[`COALESCE`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) method return the first non-null parameter . so if `b.column2` is null then it will return 0 .